# Comprehensive textbook on modern military hardware?

Tags: warfare, military-defense

Can anybody recommend a comprehensive textbook on military hardware that would include not only American but French, German etc arms too?

Comment: A printed book? Why not use the internet? Also, I'm voting to close, a recommendation for a book isn't about Worldbuilding. Try [the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), to see what is appropriate on this site.

Comment: You may want to check out the [Military Combat](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/83054/military-combat) proposed site.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, we always used to rely upon [Jane's Guides](http://www.janes.com/) on Ships, Aircraft, etc.  [These books are comprehensive analyses of military (and some civilian) hardware around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane%27s_Information_Group).

They often contained information on the derivation of different pieces of hardware too and other interesting facts.

Unfortunately, the site will charge you for access to the Guides, however, a good library might have copies (or a subscription) to the site.